# Can ZZ from NTL be used to represent big numbers needed fro crypto?

Tags: openssl, bignum, ntl

I'm trying to implement [Threshold Elgamal](https://www.scs.carleton.ca/sites/default/files/course_page/secretsharing.pdf) and I need a library that supports both big numbers and polynomials. For polynomials I would use [NTL](http://www.shoup.net/ntl/) and for big numbers I would choose openssl bignum. The problem is that the big numbers must be the coefficients of the polynomials, which in NTL are either `ZZ` or `ZZ_p`.

The [description of `ZZ` says](http://www.shoup.net/ntl/doc/ZZ.cpp.html): "big integers": signed, arbitrary length integers.

Is this enough?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ZZ` can store any integer you want.

`ZZ_p` represents numbers modulo `p` (any intager, not necessarily prime), where `p` is of type `ZZ`, so it can also be any (positive) integer you want.

The classes for polynomials are `ZZX` and `ZZ_pX`. Here is the limitation, that the degree of the polynomials have to be of type `long`, so I think it has an upper bound of 2³¹-1, since the degree is a signed `long` and the zero polynomial has degree -1 (by definition in NTL).

But notice, that you should compile NTL with GMP to get the best performance using big integers.